# NuGet package addressing multiple Standard frameworks - problem with nullables

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, nullable, .net-standard

We have a series of .Net Core 3.1 applications.  We abstracted out common code as .NetStandard 2.1 NuGet packages and made those available on our private NuGet server.

Such was the success of these NuGet packages, we have been asked to make them available to our other applications that are written in the .Net Framework 4.8.

We followed the advice given by Microsoft ([Support multiple .NET Framework versions in your project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file)) and this has worked just fine for all but one of our packages....

So - what's different about this one?

This package uses nullables.  I can get the project to compile just fine, but it is the Test project (.NetCore 3.1) that is throwing exceptions.  I'll go through the code changes we made in the Standard project first, then look at the Test project - hopefully someone will spot where we've gone wrong.

> The .Net Standard project

**.csproj file**

Changed

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

Also moved `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` to its own section

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2_1' ">
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**The class**

We then have a class file.  I won't bother showing the base class, but it follows a similar pattern:

```
public class MyClass<T> : MyBaseClass
        where T : struct
{
    public MyClass()
        : this(default)
    {
    }

#if netstandard2_1
    public MyClass(T? item)
        : base(true, 0, null)
    {
        this.Item = item;
    }
#else
    public MyClass(T item)
        : base(true, 0, null)
    {
        this.Item = item;
    }
#endif

#if netstandard2_1
    public T? Item { get; set; }
#else
    public T Item { get; set; }
#endif
}
```

This compiles and in the bin/release folder (or bin/debug) you see two folders, one for `netstandard2.1` and another for `netstandard2.0` with the expected DLL in each.

However, inspecting this class in both DLLs with ILSPY shows them to be identical...not a question mark to be seen.  Not sure if this is an artifact of ILSPY or real....

> The Test Project

So the test project has a project reference to the Standard project (so, it's *not* a reference to the NuGet package).

In one of the tests I have:

```
Guid? g = null;
var actual = new ItemValueOperationResponse<Guid>(g);
```

Which results in the following error:

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'

But, this test project is .Net Core 3.1, so it should be using the Standard2.1 code.

I tried swapping the sequence in the *.csproj so it read as `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>` but to no avail.

Also tried with upper case: `#if NETSTANDARD2_1`.

Comment: In your property group, you've replaced the dot with an underscore. This value should be exactly as the item in `<TargetFrameworks>`, so it should be `'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.1'`.

Comment: Your code should use `#if NETSTANDARD2_1` (all uppercase with underscore).

Comment: As @madreflection noted, you need to use all uppercase. In Visual Studio you can use the dropdown at the top-left of the code window to change code versions. As you do so, you should see sections of you code gray out as they are eliminated.

Comment: Also take a look at your test project references, does it show the project your testing nested below a framework version?

Comment: @madreflection - the problem was, as you suggested, that I needed `$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.1'` - thanks.  One further question....when the `project under test` has "divergent" code based on the .NetStandard version, then I guess one really needs the tests to cover both.  Guess that I therefore need to have my TEST project be both .NetCore 3.1 and .NetCore 2.1.  Would you agree?

Comment: I would agree that you want to cover the code in all ways that it's compiled that are functionally different. What you described is one way to do it and I would start by doing it that way. Depending on how messy the unit test code gets, though, you may find that having separate unit test projects, each targeting a single TFM, might be easier to maintain. It depends on your tolerance for seeing around `$if`'s in your code. In-method blocks are one thing but declarations can get a bit difficult to read.

Comment: `Guid` is a struct, not a class, so `Guid?` is not type compatible with `Guid`. The `nullable` checks are only for reference types, not pass-by-value types.

Comment: @madreflection - good advice regarding the tests.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having regions in our Test project.